# Multi Input Type in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I have to set 3 types for one variable in Input in GraphQL.
I am trying make it like this:

```
input AttributeNumeric {
  key: String!
  value: [Float!]!
}

input AttributeString {
  key: String!
  value: [String!]!
}

input AttributeBoolean {
  key: String!
  value: [Boolean!]!
}

union Attribute = AttributeNumeric | AttributeString | AttributeBoolean


input PricesInput {
  values: [Attribute!]!
}

extend type Mutation {
    variantPrices(pimId: ID!, body: PricesInput!....
}
```

but problem is that values of PricesInput must be input type , not union, but also I need more types, so I cant use input.
Have someone a solution for that?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: See [issue 488](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488). This is not supported